MySQL 8.4 out of memory
We have an instance of MySQL 8.4 running on Windows Server 2022. It ran fine for 12 days, but suddenly it is consuming a lot of memory. I've deducted this from the Windows Event log and the MySQL error log.
Example: (MySQL error log) [ERROR] [MY-010934] [Server] Out of memory (Needed 1594376 bytes) and (Windows event log) The following programs consumed the most virtual memory: mysqld.exe (2944) consumed 15530082304 bytes.
Here's the whole MySQL error log: https://pastebin.com/4pcwaDHJ
Anyone who can help me figure out what might be going on?
Here's the my.ini-file: https://pastebin.com/4bSbM5Vz
The server is a VM with 24 GB RAM and runs Wordpress (PHP) under IIS.
Thanks in advance.
-Espen.

innodb_buffer_pool_size=12G. Reducing that setting to 6 GB or less seems like a good place to start.

Thanks for your reply. How should I go about doing this on a production server? Can I just shut down the service, change the pool size, and start it back up again?

Voting to close - how to tune memory for LAMP + wordpress would fill a large book.
